# React-Native error : Invariant Violation : Element type is Invalid

Tags: react-native, class, expo, element

I'm a beginner of programming world, now I practice react-native by watching some tutorials on youtube.

This is the one that I'm watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyiwFcrVRCM&list=WL&index=79&t=0s

This youtube creator even put his
Source code: https://git.io/fjLxo
Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@react-ui-kit/p...

When I copy everything from the beginnig on watching, this error

> Invariant Violation : Element type is Invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of 'App'.

occurs, and even in creator's expo, same problem happens on my mac.

My version is:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.61.5
- and I use MacOS Catalina version 10.15.3

I'll really appreciate if somebody can solve this.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This error arise when you are mixing named export with default export vice-versa

```
e.g
var user ="abc"
export const user //named export
export default user //default export
```

For e.g if you are importing like this

```
import MyDefaultComponent from "./MyDefaultExport"; //import default export module
```

replace it with

```
import {MyDefaultComponent} from "./MyDefaultExport"; //import named export module
```

checkout this article for detail understanding [named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)